# Plane and Grid are not working as Fluid Effector Collision in Blender 2.82

Tags: fluid-simulation

In my scene the liquid goes through the plane or grid, no matter what the settings are, but with a cube it works as it supposed to.

I've tried with option "is planar" checked and with surface thickness other than 0 but the effect is still the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if you want to provide files for us to check.

Comment: Hi, thank you for showing how to upload the file.

Comment: Try adding some surface thickness, something like 0.7

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.. So I added a value of 0.75 on surface thickness, and it work well !! :)

Comment: This also works if you have a mesh that's acting as a collision effector. Higher values may be needed if you increase the resolution of the simulation on the fluid domain.